# Open MSQL procedure from C# application (using System.Diagnostics)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, path

I am having difficulties in finding a solution for opening a stored procedure straight to MSQL management studio for modifying in a new SQLQuery from my `C#` application (winform).

Here is my code:

```
Process openSQL = new Process();
openSQL.StartInfo.FileName = "Ssms.exe";
openSQL.StartInfo.Arguments = "dbo.getResults"; //name of the stored procedure I want to open 
openSQL.Start();
```

I am getting error after executing the code :"The following files were specified on the command line: dbo.getResults These files could not be found and will not be loaded."

How am I supposed to "point" to the stored procedure in C# and get its definition displayed and ready to get modifications in MSQL management studio?

Comment: Why open Sql server management studio at all? You can use System.Data.SQLClient namespace which has SQLConnection and SQLCommand to open a connection to the database and run sql procedures without actually opening an instance of sql server management studio.

Comment: `ssms -?` will show you the command line options, the ability to do that is not among them. Seems an odd thing to want to to anyway.

Comment: You can't open a proc like this. Think about this, which server is it on? Which database?

Comment: Without setting  openSQL.StartInfo.Arguments  my SQL Server Management Studio is  getting opened without a problem.

Comment: Are you trying to open SSMS to show the procedure so you can edit it? Or do you just want to run the proc?

Comment: @DavidG I need to open SSMS to show the procedure so I can edit it.

Comment: In that case, no, you cannot do that. There is on way to tell SSMS to open a procedure like that.

Comment: @DavidG Can I get some ideas for something close to my question ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything you can really do other than coding up your own UI which seems a bit drastic. Why do you want to do this anyway? If people are using SSMS then they should be capable of editing procs manually.

Comment: Yeah this is a strange thing to want to do in the first place.   DavidG should post his comment as the answer to close the question.

Comment: @TabAlleman I did come up with some options though, still prefer letting people use SSMS on their own though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to open a stored procedure script straight to MSQL management studio for modifying in a new SQLQuery from my C# application (winform).

1. I am taking the script of the procedure with `EXEC sp_helptext 'procedure_name'`
2. The result set is filled in a DataSet
3. And the DataSet is getting written in an empty .sql file
4. The .sql file is getting opened in MSQL Managment Studio with `System.Diagnostics;`

Here are the steps with code snippets:

```
 private void saveProcToAFile()
 {
     StreamWriter log;

     if (!File.Exists("procedureToBeLoaded.sql"))
     {
         log = new StreamWriter("procedureToBeLoaded.sql");
     }
     else
     {        
         log = new StreamWriter(File.Create("procedureToBeLoaded.sql"));
     }           

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = string.Format("EXEC sp_helptext '{0}'", "procedure_name"); //Step 1.
     da.SelectCommand = cmd;
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     conn.Open();
     da.Fill(ds); //Step 2.
     conn.Close();

     foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
         log.WriteLine(dr[0]); //Step 3.
     }

     log.Close();          
  }
```

Step 4.

```
private void contextMenuStripOpenInSqlStudio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveProcToAFile();
    Process openSQL = new Process();
    openSQL.StartInfo.FileName = "Ssms.exe";
    openSQL.StartInfo.Arguments = "procedureToBeLoaded.sql";
    openSQL.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible I'm afraid. If you run `ssms -?` from the command line you can see all the parameters that you can pass in:

[image]

Some options:

1. Let users edit procs themselves. After all, anyone capable of doing this will understand how to use SSMS properly.
2. Make your own UI. You can read the contents of a stored procedure and display them in a text box. The downside is that you lose features such as syntax highlighting (unless you also build that in too)
3. You could download the procedure and store it in a `procedure.sql` file and get SSMS to open that. Don't forget to pass in the server, database and credentials.